# Does escape fragment works without a hash in the URL?

Tags: seo, javascript, angular.js

I have done SEO for a site in angularjs 1 using phantomjs. The site has enabled html5 mode true so there will be no "#!" in the URL. I have added a check for `$args ~ _escaped_fragment_`.

Will search engine bots visit the site with `_escaped_fragment_` in URL ?

Answer (score 3):

The escaped fragment crawling scheme was [created by Google to make AJAX sites crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more).  However, it shouldn't be used anymore.  Googlebot now knows how to crawl AJAX websites, especially those that change the URL using pushState (html5 mode).   In fact [Google has deprecated the escaped fragment crawling](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) and soon won't support it.